# I wonder why this happen when using no await return

Tags: node.js, typeorm

```js
async noAwaitFunction(){
   const queryRunner = this.datatSource.createQueryRunner("master");
   try{
     return this.repo.createQueryBuilder(SomeEntity,queryRunner).find();
   }cath(err){
      throw err;
   }finally{
     await queryRunner.release();
   }
}
```

"I'm encountering an issue where, after calling noAwaitFunction() multiple times, error tracking doesn't work, and at some point, I get a 'pool does not exist' error. I don't understand why this is happening. I know that if I return without await, errors within the function context aren't caught, but does this mean my created queryRunner isn't being released either?"

i change my code to use return await ~~ . then this does not happened

Answer (score 2):

> I know that if I return without await, errors within the function context aren't caught, but does this mean my created queryRunner isn't being released either?

No, it means it's being released **too early**. Your code is starting a `find` operation, then releasing the `queryRunner` before it's complete (because the `finally` block's code runs before the promise from `find` settles). What happens at that point depends on the internals of the library you're using, but apparently it's not designed to be used like that. With the `await` on the line starting with `return`, the `finally` block doesn't get executed until the promise from `find` settles (is fulfilled or rejected).

Here's a simple example showing the problem:

```js
function find(thingToFindWith) {
    console.log("Starting find");
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Finishing find");
            const stuff = thingToFindWith.doSomething();
            resolve(stuff);
        }, 100);
    });
}

async function example() {
    const thingToFindWith = {
        close() {
            this.closed = true;
        },
        doSomething() {
            if (this.closed) {
                throw new Error("Thing is closed");
            }
            console.log("Using thing to find stuff");
            return "stuff";
        }
    };
    try {
        return find(thingToFindWith);
    } finally {
        console.log("Running finally block");
        thingToFindWith.close();
    }
}

example()
.then((stuff) => console.log("Result: " + stuff));
```

Compared to:

```js
function find(thingToFindWith) {
    console.log("Starting find");
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Finishing find");
            const stuff = thingToFindWith.doSomething();
            resolve(stuff);
        }, 100);
    });
}

async function example() {
    const thingToFindWith = {
        close() {
            this.closed = true;
        },
        doSomething() {
            if (this.closed) {
                throw new Error("Thing is closed");
            }
            console.log("Using thing to find stuff");
            return "stuff";
        }
    };
    try {
        return await find(thingToFindWith);
    } finally {
        console.log("Running finally block");
        thingToFindWith.close();
    }
}

example()
.then((stuff) => console.log("Result: " + stuff));
```